# three table join data from first and third

Tags: mysql, join

I have three database tables (MySQL) simplified to the info below:

```
===============
member
---------------
id
FirstName
===============
```

member.id = quote_details.member_id

```
===============
quote_details
---------------
member_id
insurer_id
===============
```

quote_details.insurer_id = insurer.id

```
===============
insurer
---------------
id
Name
===============
```

What I would like to output is `member.FirstName` and `insurer.Name`, so I understand that I will require joins between all the tables - i.e. member > quote_details and then quote_details > insurer. I'm struggling with the join types though and hoping that someone will be able to point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Regards,

Neil

edit to clarify:

I have tried `INNER JOIN` across the three but that returns a list of all the insurers with the FirstName of the queried member:

```
==========================
FirstName | Insurer
--------------------------
Test      | Insurer One
Test      | Insurer Two
Test      | Insurer Three
==========================
```

Where as I'm only requiring the actual insurer who is assigned to the member's quote. I hope this helps clarify things a little.

edit to add sample data:

```
===================
member
-------------------
id | FirstName
- - - - - - - - - -
 1 | Test
 2 | John
 3 | Jane
===================

=======================
quote_details
-----------------------
member_id | insurer_id
- - - - - - - - - - - -
        1 |          1
=======================

===================
insurer
-------------------
id | Name
- - - - - - - - - -
 1 | Insurer One
 2 | Insurer Two
 3 | Insurer Three
===================
```

This hopefully provides all the clarity now :¬)

Comment: First step towards determinig the proper join type is defining which records should appear in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, an `INNER JOIN` will suffice your needs if both columns in table `quote_details` are *non-nullable* columns.

```
SELECT  b.FirstName MemberName,
        c.Name InsurerName
FROM    quote_details a
        INNER JOIN member b
            ON a.member_ID = b.id
        INNER JOIN insurer c
            ON a.insurer_ID = c.ID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is what I did try initially, but the problem is it then returns a list of all the insurers - not the insurer that is assigned to the quote and quote assigned to the member.
`FirstName, Insurer`
`--------------------`
`Test, Insurer One`
`Test, Insurer Two`
`Test, Insurer Three`
I hope this helps..

Comment: Did you try to execute the query? I think you missed the point here. As you can see, we are joining `quote_details` two columns againts the two tables: `member` and `insurer` via their `ID`.

Comment: to make it more clear, can you give sample records (*atleast 3-4 records on each*) with your desired result so we can play with the data.

Comment: I've added sample data to the original question, how this helps.

Comment: oh, i see it but i have a small question. In table `quote_details`, I only see record `1, 1`, why is it returns all the records on insurer when it only matched on one record on table `insurer`? Maybe you have missed something in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is set up to allow a member to have multiple insurers (and vice versa).  If you want all of insurers on the same row, you'll need to do an aggregation:

```
select m.FirstName, group_concat(i.Name separator ', ') as Insurers
from member m inner join
     quote_details qd
     ON qd.member_ID = m.id inner join
     insurer i
     ON qd.insurer_ID = i.ID
group by m.FirstName
```

When giving tables aliases, use reasonable abbreviations rather than "a", "b", "c", etc. The reasonable abbreviations make the query much easier to understand.

If you have members with no insurers, they will not appear in the output.  If you want all of them, then use `left outer join`:

```
select m.FirstName, group_concat(i.Name separator ', ') as Insurers
from member m left outer join
     quote_details qd
     ON qd.member_ID = m.id left outer join
     insurer i
     ON qd.insurer_ID = i.ID
group by m.FirstName
```

If you want them on separate rows:

```
select m.FirstName, i.Name
from quote_details qd inner join
     member m
     ON qd.member_ID = m.id inner join
     insurer i
     ON qd.insurer_ID = i.ID
```